# How to configure default Where clause in Hibernate Entity (POJO) HQL

Tags: class, entity, default, where-clause, clause

I have set of entity (POJO) classes, Each entity class will have one property stopDate , which is type of Date.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORG")
public class Organization extends PersistentObjImpl {

private Long odbid;                 //ODBID                                     NUMBER(11)   i.e.  Primary Key
private String actionFeedReqInd;
private String alternateName;
private Date stopDate;              //STOP_DATE                                 NOT NULL DATE


@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="STOP_DATE",  nullable=false)
public Date getStopDate() {
    return stopDate;
}

public void setStopDate(Date stopDate) {
    this.stopDate = stopDate;
}
     //setter and getter methods for corresponding columns i.e. properties 

   }
```

in Organization Database table, if any row's stop_date column value is less than current date(sysdate)  , we should not fetch those rows using Hibernate.

Ex: Org data base table.

ODBID    Column1 Column2  stop_date
1          -      -       2015-02-13
2          -      -       2010-04-23
3          -      -       2009-03-13

Here is the SQL statement and Output ,which I am expecting.

SELECT ODBID, , from ORG WHERE stop_date>sysdate ;

ODBID    Column1 Column2  stop_date
1          -      -       2015-02-13

Like this , I have so many tables, which has stop_date as column, from any one of the table, if the stop_date < sysdate, i don't want to retrieve those records ..

I am not interested to write stop_date>sysdate condition in each SQL/HQL select query. Is there any way I can configure this condition once, and use in all the Entity (POJO ) classes.

Please provide me a generic way.